# Swift: Syntax Translation

Tags: swift, xcode6, xcode6.1

Need help with translating code below into Swift.

Objective-C Code (Works great):

```
- (UIViewController *)getViewControllerFromStoryboard:(NSString *)storyboardName sceneName:(NSString*)sceneName iconName:(NSString*)icon title:(NSString*)title
{
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:sceneName];
    UIImage *tabIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:icon];

    vc.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:title image:tabIcon selectedImage:nil];
    vc.title = NSLocalizedString(title,nil);

    return vc;
}
```

Translation to Swift:

```
func getViewControllerFromStoryBoar(storyboardName: String, sceneName: String, iconName: String, title: String) -> UIViewController{
    let sb : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
    let vc = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(sceneName)  //Warning A
    let tabIcon : UIImage = UIImage(named: iconName)!
    vc.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(initWithTitle:title, image:tabIcon) //Error A
    vc.title = title //Error B

    return vc as UIViewController

}
```

**Warning A:**  Constant 'vc' inferred to have type 'AnyObject!', which may be unexpected
Why 'AnyObject!' ?  This seems to fix the error

**Error A:** Cannot assign to 'tabBarItem' in 'vc'

**Error B:** Cannot assign to 'title' in 'vc'

I don't understand the two errors above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error A: Cannot assign to 'tabBarItem' in 'vc'
>
> Error B: Cannot assign to 'title' in 'vc'

Because `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` returns an AnyObject. That is what the warning was warning you! You should have paid attention to that warning. (You silenced the warning; that was the wrong thing to do. Don't silence it; *listen* to it.)

You need to cast this reference down before you can work with it. I know *you* know it is a UIViewController, but Swift doesn't know this; you have to cast and tell it.

```
let vc = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(sceneName) as UIViewController
```

That will solve the whole thing in one move.